# How can I extract all different rows from a dataframe in R

Tags: r

I have a table with repeated rows and I need to extract all different rows from that table.
The first 10 lines of the table are..

```
        m         t              d               
 [1,] "ausente" "bovino"       "bife/costeleta"
 [2,] "ausente" "bovino"       "inteiro"       
 [3,] "ausente" "bovino"       "miudezas"      
 [4,] "ausente" "bovino"       "peca"          
 [5,] "ausente" "bovino"       "peq_peca"      
 [6,] "ausente" "bovino"       "preparado"     
 [7,] "ausente" "bovino"       "semi-preparado"
 [8,] "ausente" "bovino/suino" "bife/costeleta"
 [9,] "ausente" "bovino/suino" "inteiro"       
 [10,] "ausente" "bovino/suino" "miudezas"
```

Comment: Do you want unique rows to be extracted?

Comment: try `mytable[!duplicated(mytable),]`

Answer (score 2):

You can just use `unique`

```
 unique(d1)
```